# Significant Build Time Difference between Local and Remote Teams on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Description:**

We're experiencing a perplexing issue with our build process that's causing a substantial delay for our team compared to our remote team in Croatia. While the build process takes around 5-10 seconds for them, it's taking us a frustrating 5-10 minutes. Our suspicion is that a download might be causing the delay, but we're unable to identify what's being downloaded.

**Setup:**

We're using C# and react
We are running the code in Visual Stuido
We have 13 projects inside our solution
The remote team in Croatia experiences normal build times.

**Differences:**

Our local team and remote team both use different hardware setups, but nothing overly powerful on either side.
Network connectivity could be a factor, but we've tested our network speeds and haven't noticed any significant differences.
No notable differences in configuration files or build scripts.

**Debugging Attempts:**

Checked logs for any error messages or warnings, but found nothing substantial.
Monitored network activity during the build process using [Network Monitoring Tool], but couldn't identify the source of the download.
Profiling the build process didn't reveal any specific bottlenecks.

**Hypothesis:**

We're suspecting that the extended build time might be due to a download happening during our build process, but we're unsure what's being downloaded.
As shown here:
[image: Downloading Packages]

Its slowing down on projects 3,5,6,7,9
But here are the projects, but we dont know how to debug this step either.
[image]

Here are the two videos us building the projects side by side, you can clearly see the difference.

**Long:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UUj89K5l58jbgJn_vMTxG3iGg_eCINsU/view?usp=drive_link

**Short:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WGpfSAeDJcr5O1yhLZqAqAnaqAsqOI-w/view?usp=sharing

**Questions:**

1. How can we more effectively monitor network activity during the build process to identify what's being downloaded?
2. Are there any tools or techniques that could help us pinpoint the cause of this significant delay?
3. Could there be any hidden factors that we're not considering that might explain this difference in build times?
4. Any suggestions on how to further diagnose this issue and narrow down potential causes?

Comment: I've noticed that the source code is in user profile folder. Does it still happen if the source code is outside that path? Try sth like `c:\src`. In Windows user profiles can be stored on the server (Roaming User Profiles) and maybe your remote team has longer access times to that server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `1.`. ProcExp from Sysinternals may help

My main suggestion is that for `2.`, `3.` and `4.`, you need to build with binary logs enabled and then you can really investigate what is taking up any part of the build with a tool called [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer].(https://msbuildlog.com/)

It's intimidating to look at binlogs because there is so much data but it will help you quickly narrow down what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually the antivirus we had installed that was slowing down the entire process. We made certain exclusions, to the project solution and some packages we had and it seems like we cut it from 5 min to 40 sec. So that was really good for us! We will try to get it down even more, but for now its good.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people